# What path doesn't return the value?

Tags: c++, recursion, warnings, binary-search-tree

I have a function to find the node in BST by its string key, using recursion.
I'm getting the warning for second function : c4715 "not all control paths return a value". I can't understand what exactly path doesn't return the value..

Here's my functions:

```
TreeNode* Tree::findNodeByKey(const string &str) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        cout << "Tree is empty, nothing found" << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    else {
        return findNodeByKeyHelper(root, str);
    }
}

TreeNode* Tree::findNodeByKeyHelper(TreeNode *node, const string &str) {
    if (node->data == str) {
        cout << "node is found" << endl;
        return node;
    }
     else if (str < node->data) {
        if (node->left == nullptr) {
            cout << "element was not found" << endl;
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            findNodeByKeyHelper(node->left, str);
        }
    }
     else if (str > node->data) {
        if (node->right == nullptr) {
            cout << "element was not found" << endl;
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            findNodeByKeyHelper(node->right, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not all pathes in `Tree::findNodeByKeyHelper()` return a value obviously.

Comment: "*not all control paths return a value*". Search for a path that doesn't end in a `return` statement.

Comment: I just don't understand where I don't return the value. That's the problem, otherwise I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: @kekyc The statement `findNodeByKeyHelper(node->left, str);` doesn't return a value, unless you explicitly say it: `return findNodeByKeyHelper(node->left, str);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just added `return` to 2 `findNodeByKeyHelper()` calls. Got the same situation. Compiler still tells me "not all control paths return a value".

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, because it removed the problem from the code. Solutions should be in answers, not edited into the question. Readers need to be able to see what the original problem was and how the answer fixed it.

Comment: @kekyc though it may not seem logical to you, there is *still* a path that doesn't return a value. if `str` answers false to all three comparison operators (they're overloads), you wind up at the bottom of the function with no return result. See if you can lose the last comparison and just make it an `else {`

Comment: @WhozCraig you're certainly right. Thank you for your answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These paths

```
else if (str < node->data) {
    if (node->left == nullptr) {
        cout << "element was not found" << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        findNodeByKeyHelper(node->left, str);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
 else if (str > node->data) {
    if (node->right == nullptr) {
        cout << "element was not found" << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        findNodeByKeyHelper(node->right, str);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

return nothing.

You should insert the return keyword. For example

```
        return findNodeByKeyHelper(node->right, str);
```

And substitute the last `else-if` for `else`. For example

```
if (node->data == str) {
    //...
}
 else if (str < node->data) {
    //...
}
 else  {
 ^^^^^^^
    //...
}
```

Comment: Oh. You're certainly right, thank you very much! But as I thought, my recursion should anyway end in case of "element was not found" or "node was found". Am I right?

Comment: @kekyc In some level of the seach the function indeed will return either a node or nullpt to the preceding levelr. But on the preceding level the function will return nothing.

Comment: Indeed... Thanks for your explanation!:)

Comment: Hrm. Just added `return` to 2 `findNodeByKeyHelper()` calls as you adviced. But I got the same situation. Compiler still tells me "not all control paths return a value".

Comment: @kekyc Substitute the last else-if to else.